# Probability of true and False Questions

Tags: probability

On a true-false test, each question has exactly one correct answer: true, or false. A student knows the correct answer to 70% of the questions on the test. Each of the remaining answers she guesses at random, independently of all other answers. After the test has been graded, one of the questions is picked at random. Given that she got the answer right, what is the chance that she knew the answer?

R is the event that she gets the answer Right.
 K is the event she Knows the answer.

P(R|K) = 1
 P(K) = 0.7
P(R|K) means she gets the answer right, given she knew the answer. 
P(R|K') means she gets the answer right, but did not know the answer.
P(R)=P(K)P(R|K)+P(K′)P(R|K′)

P(R) = P(R|K)+P(R|K') = 0.7 + 0.15 = 0.85

P(K|R)=(P(R|K)×P(K))/P(R)=

=((1)*(0.70))/(0.85)=0.8235=she knew the answer approx...82.35%???

Comment: The answer (and method) are correct.

Comment: In the fourth paragraph, you should have $P(R)=P(K)P(R|K)+P(K')P(R|K')$. This is what you computed after the second equality, though.